# Probability function over infinite set

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Hmm, I was just talking to a friend of mine...and I said that

> Personally I would like to define the discrete probability function to be $ |event|\over |sample space|$

Then I gave an example about rolling a fair die P(outcome is even)=$|2,4,6| \over |1,2,3,4,5,6|$ which is 50%, and my friend asked me if it worked with infinite discrete set...without thinking too much I said...of course, if the numerator is all **even positive integers** and the denominator is **all positive integers**, then I know the probability is going to be 50%

but later, when I tried to prove it mathematically...I failed, since I know that set of **even positive integers** and **all positive integers** have the same cardinality...the one to one mapping is just times two

so...my function should return me 1? I know this is not making sense...can someone help me...I think somehow I confused myself :(

Comment: are you sure it is 50%? is the die fair?

Comment: @BCLC, good question I think this probability function will only work when each element in the sample space is equally likely, if this is not the case...maybe we need to introduce a gcd?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no uniform density function on a countable set such as the integers - that is, there is no way to define a probability distribution for which every integer is an equally likely output.

But a related concept is [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) or asymptotic density, which will (in some sense) capture the intuition that the evens and odds pair up as they do for finite sets.

Comment: I don't really get the first sentence, are you saying that we can't define a probability function over countable set like integers because of non-uniform density function(what does it mean...)? can you give me a counter example? ie something with a uniform density function and what would the probability function look like? thanks :)

Comment: What I am saying is that there is no way to define a pdf so that every integer has equal weight. We can define a density on the positive integers by something like $p(1) = 1/2$, $p(2) = 1/4$, $p(3) = 1/8$, and so on.